# macOS app cannot open file that exists

Tags: c, macos, fopen

I have a C module in a Xcode app (macOS) that opens a file.

Here is the code:

```
char fname1 [1028] = "/Library/Preferences/tbupdd.ini";
FILE * fp;

fp = fopen(fname1, "r");

if (fp == NULL)
{
    perror("error opening updd.ini");
    printf("File %s not found, use another method for getting version\n", fname1);
    exit(1);
}
```

The file exists and I can read it in Terminal. But running this app in Xcode is giving

```
error opening updd.ini: Operation not permitted
```

The file has the following permissions:

```
$ ls -l /Library/Preferences/tbupdd.ini
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  25584 20 Dec 15:05 /Library/Preferences/tbupdd.ini
```

I understand that Xcode has a working directory but would that affect the above absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern macOS apps employ sandboxing, that only allow updates to files in the sandbox. See [File System Programming Guide: The Library Directory Stores App-Specific Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1). Also see [About App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183).

I would not suggest using a hard coded path like that. I'd suggest getting the library folder from the `NSFileManager`

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:true error:&error];
NSAssert(!error, @"Unable to get library directory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
NSLog(@"%s", fileURL.path.UTF8String);
```

That returns:

> /Users/{username}/Library/Containers/{com.domain.app}/Data/Library

You can then pass that to your C function.

---

BTW, Apple explicitly advises that we should not create files in `Preferences` subfolder. They [warn us](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1):

> This directory contains app-specific preference files. You should not create files in this directory yourself. Instead, use the [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults) class or `CFPreferences` API to get and set preference values for your app.

Comment: Thanks Rob. BTW, it's not me that has put this file in the Preferences folder - its a 3rd party and I'm trying to write something that works with what they have done.

Comment: So, does this mean there is no way to access the file with the path "/Library/Preferences/tbupdd.ini" from the Xcode app? Or is there some sort of virtual mapping going on?

Comment: You can present the user a `NSOpenPanel` where they can select that `ini` file (which is a really ugly UX) or turn off sandboxing in your target settings "Capabilities" tab (which, AFAIK, limits your ability to distribute the app on the App Store and smart end-users will be reluctant to install because of the security problems un-sandboxed apps potentially introduce). Maybe someone else knows other ways around this, but I don't.

Comment: This will be an internal app available to very few users so (mercifully) App Store hurdles are not an issue.

Comment: Then try turning off "sandboxing" on the "Capabilities" tab. And I'd suggest creating a ticket with the third-party provider to create a sandbox-compatible "settings" approach (though I recognize that you might not have much success there if they're still living in a non-sandboxed world; lol).

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.2 . Where would I find the Capabilities tab?

Comment: It's in your "target" settings: Go to the "navigation" panel on the left » click on the app name at the top of that file navigation tree » select your main app "target" » click on "Capabilities" tab » "App Sandbox" is the first item listed under those capabilities.